# Lower the limit for when users can review flags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

If older flags are being aged away because there aren't enough people to approve or reject them, like this question suggests [Why were my older close flags "aged away"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away) , then would it be worth lowering the limit on when members can review them?

For example if the community dropped the limit to those with a reputation of 1.5k to be able to review flags then that would clear them quicker.
If needed then a flag could be approved with the sign off from one member over 1.5k but another over 2k?

Comment: No, we don't need to lower the limit.  What we need is to get the people who can review to review.  Only a small fraction of the total people that can review actually do.

Comment: What percentage of people that can review do review?

Comment: Also if flags are getting aged away and those that can review aren't doing so then don't other options need to be looked at? I am making one suggestion that could be implemented but you have just made a comment about more people who can reviewing with no comment on how that would be done?

Comment: I don't have the exact numbers but there are 80K+ people with close vote privileges.  That many people could review ~16K reviews per day.  Right now we're more than half way through the day and we have only done ~1K review.

Comment: But are those 80k people active on the site? If they aren't then they don't really count. In any case is my suggestion realistic or not, or is it something that could be open to discussion?

Comment: I'm not sure.  They all have 3K+ rep and generally higher rep people are active so I would say a good chunk of them are.

Comment: Makes sense. Has getting more people to review been addressed anywhere that I have missed?

Comment: There was [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319633/encourage-users-to-review-posts).  There are probably others, just not enough time to search for them now.

Comment: Thanks you. I will have a look.

Comment: We need to raise the bar for being able to _flag_, not lower the bar for review. A good percentage of what I review in the close vote queue for stuff that doesn't have any close votes (was flagged by someone with less than 3K rep) does not need to be closed at all. If I didn't waste all that time clicking "leave open" on stuff that doesn't need to be closed, I could spend more time closing stuff that _does_ need to be closed.

Comment: Lots of people review, there are ~2500 new reviewers every week.  But only ~7000 of them are active per week.  It is galley slave labor, people just burn out on it in less than a month.  Having them burn out sooner doesn't help anybody.

Comment: If people burn out quickly then how about the opposite of what I have suggested and limit how many they can review for the first few weeks or until their reputation gets higher again?

Comment: @ChrisM there is a limit of 20 reviews per queue per day.

Comment: @NathanOliver According to my SEDE query, there are 33k users over 3k reputation only that have been active in the last 30 days.

Comment: @NathanOliver and whoever finds it interesting: I wrote [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/715853/breakdown-of-how-many-people-of-eligibility-have-completed-reviews-lately) query to analyze how many eligible reviewers were on vs how many review tasks have been completed in the last 30 days using SEDE. Results: 161122 users above 500 reputation were online at least once in 30 days and in that timespan 146666 first post and late answers reviews were completed. 55326 users above 2k were on and 175280 suggested edit and low quality post reviews were completed,

Comment: 37970 users above 3k were on and 65744 close and reopen reviews were completed.

Comment: @Magisch Cool, thanks.  Look like for close and reopen reviews then it averages to 1/30th of the reviews that could be done are being done.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments, it is good to see some suggestions on what might help and I see why my suggestion might not help reduce the queues in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the [review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review), the one that desperately needs more reviewers is the [Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/) queue. While the others have a manageable number of posts that can be adequately handled by the available reviewers, Close Votes has hovered at *well* over 5k posts for quite some time now, recently sitting at >9k for many months.

The problem with this queue is that reviewing effectively requires the reviewer to have [close vote privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), which you don't earn until 3k reputation.

So…basically what you are proposing here is that the close vote privilege be reduced, and I just can't get behind that proposal. We intentionally set this privilege at a relatively high reputation level to ensure that the only people who get to close other people's questions are those with a good grasp of what is/is not suitable for this site. In order to make valid decisions regarding closure, you need a non-trivial amount of experience *on this website in particular*, and that's what reputation most accurately measures.

I agree that we need to figure out a way to reduce the number of close flags that age away, because that's a horrible system—off-topic questions don't get more on-topic just because there aren't enough people to close them. I just don't think this is the right solution. Instead, I would prefer increasing the *weight* of close votes for experts, especially those users who hold gold badges in relevant tags. They are the most capable of assessing whether a question is on-topic, clear, or too broad. I personally think they should have *binding* votes, just as they do for duplicates, but even if you can't get behind that, you should be able to get behind doubling or tripling the weight of their votes.

Comment: A quick [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/715853/breakdown-of-how-many-people-of-eligibility-have-completed-reviews-lately) shows that 37970 users that can close or reopen have been active in the last 30 days and those have completed a total of 65744 close & reopen reviews in the same timespan.

Comment: Cool numberz. Dunno what they mean, though.

Comment: That 37970 users have all together completed a total of 65744 close and reopen reviews in the last 30 days.

Comment: I wasn't proposing the close vote privilege be reduced. I was proposing the limit for reviewing was lowered. If the only queue that doesn't get cleared is the closed review then I guess it does suggest that, although I wasn't aware of that before. Thanks for the feedback, it was interesting to get a bit more insight into how the reviewing builds up.

Comment: @Chris How would you propose that one review questions for closure if he didn't have close-vote privileges? What actions would be available to you in the queue? (Oh, guess your edit answered that. Okay then.)

Comment: The question wasn't aimed at closure reviews. I am only aware that that is the queue that builds up most because of your answer. Are the only reviews to be aged away closure reviews? Yes, had edited after, you were to quick to reply :)

Comment: Yes, closure reviews (and possibly re-open reviews, but they're just two sides of the same coin) are the only ones that age away. The other ones get adequately handled by the community. Low Quality Posts (which is fed by "not an answer" and "very low quality" flags) are escalated to moderators if the community doesn't handle them. It's worth noting that [it only takes 500 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) to get started reviewing right now; you just can't access certain review queues that require more privileges to take meaningful action.