# Is it dangerous to patrol a tag with issues?

Tags: discussion, support, voting, serial-voting

I recently got a hobby of watching a certain problematic tag, where about 95% of the questions are basically crap. I added it to my favorite tags, so I can go about downvoting, voting to close and voting to delete with one click, whenever I feel like being evil in the name of good (joking, I *do* check the question contents carefully before voting).

My question: is there a risk of me getting automatically flagged for abusing the voting privileges, serial downvoting, or something else negative like that?

Bonus question: Assuming doing this is technically ok, is it also a good and positive thing to do (assuming I have nothing better to do with my life at the time)?

Comment: Serial voting only applies when you are down-/up-voting a particular users posts. Otherwise it OK what you are doing, if not appreciated.

Comment: what is your technical expertise in this tag, are you familiar / proficient in topics it cover?

Comment: They only I could see is you may accidentally serial vote someone if they post multiple questions and you happen to hit them all.

Comment: I'd worry about the effect of constantly wading through shit. Maybe you just have more patience for it than I do. I've done what you are doing and decided that my happiness was more important than trying to moderate the flow of shit armed with nothing more than a teaspoon. Note I'm not saying "don't moderate", but you might want to pick your battles. There's a tag that I used to be very active in that I no longer visit because the flow of crap just got to be too much. (Contrary to what people crying on Meta about closure and downvotes think, there's no joy in closing and downvoting Q after Q.)

Comment: [tag:seo].  [tag:seo] never changes.

Comment: @Will [Commit to SEO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/seo)

Comment: Users have been thrown in the slammer when they cause too many other users to complain.  You are pretty safe if you only ever DV since such votes are anonymous so nobody knows to complain about you.  If 95% is junk then there is something wrong with the tag.  A more constructive way to go about it that isn't such a hopeless task and time-sink is to expose the [tag] at meta.

Comment: @HansPassant: "*Users have been thrown in the slammer when they cause too many other users to complain.*" Who? When? Where did this happen? Show someone who was "thrown in the slammer" for nothing more than causing "too many other users to complain?" That is, as opposed to acting in detriment to the site.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I commit to burning it with fire.

Comment: Go read [the initial announcement for the suspend feature](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), @Nicol, under heading "Disruptive behavior" - causing complaints is *the charter* for suspend. Although mods rarely ever have to worry about someone who does *nothing more* than generate complaints.

Comment: @gnat Yes, I have sufficient echnical expertise I think, but in this case the questions causing the trouble are basically not programming questions at all, they are software questions not related to programming, and any computer-literate programmer can see them as such. But that is indeed something to consider before picking a tag to watch!

Comment: @HansPassant The tag has been exposed in meta (that's how I stumbled upon it). The good thing is, the number of questions in the tag actually gets less and less, there is visible progress.

Comment: since it's technically comfortable comfortable to you to evaluate questions in this tag I think it is really good idea for you to "patrol" it. I wrote some considerations about this in [How can I best help with Close Votes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285534/839601) "If you think of it, this makes perfect sense..." etc

Comment: "assuming I have nothing better to do with my life at the time" Given that you are asking this question, I don't need to assume.

Comment: @Gothdo Nope. It's actually the tag mentioned in Brad's answer.

Comment: You're not "abusing" voting privileges. You're using them exactly as nature intended, and much more of us should be doing the same thing:)

Comment: I don't think this is a very positive approach, though I don't think it should be forbidden. The reason I don't think that it's a good practice is simply that it probably means -- either at baseline because of predisposition or as a result of repeated negative interactions with the tag -- you're more likely to downvote or flag posts in that tag than a neutral party. This seems unfair to people who use the tag. The fact that you're asking for opinions on this is a good sign though.

Comment: @Hack-R I'm not closely familiar with the tag in question, but most tags I see are like this: people upvote anything simple enough that they understand it (hello, hot network posts!), even if it is completely off-topic or useless. Even the worst of the worst seem to gather a few upvotes. So talking about "neutral parties" is a bit misleading. Neutral parties let all the crap we have persist and multiply. hyde can be entirely neutral and still downvote and close all the crap, and rightly so. High-traffic tags are especially murder. To a healthy state of mind, I mean.

Comment: It's dangerous insofar as intensive patroling might lead to mental exhaustion. I'm happy with my favorite tags where I feel comfortable answering and I'm interested in and the crap rate is well below 50%. I'm not so much interested in everything else.

Comment: Here's my personal horror query: `[stack-overflow] [legal] [licensing] [microsoft] [copyright] [software] [creative-commons] [lgpl] [gpl] [ownership] [blogs] [open-source] [jobs] [apple] [driver] [drivers] [linux] [privacy] [design] [webpage] [networking] [vpn] [seo] [linuxmint] [archlinux] [setting] [settings] [web] [grub] [api] [api-design] [web-crawler] [ubuntu] [spam] [protection] [search-engine] [sysadmin] [kali-linux] [code-smell] [naming-conventions] [naming] [operating-system]`

Comment: @NicolBolas wrt that slammer comment from Hans it looks accurate to me, he probably experienced it himself or spoke to someone who experienced this. I think so because I myself has got mod warning (on another site) for causing "too many other users to complain". Per what I read at meta such a warning is followed by suspension if users doesn't cooperate (I agreed to cooperate so it didn't went further)

Comment: @Kyll comment reported for masochism and deviant behaviour.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan now, if that was [a suspension reason](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2743287#2743287)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Not really, and the help can be appreciated in certain areas (I'm looking at you, [kali-linux](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331586/free-us-from-the-cycle-of-kali-linux)). I regularly watch a handful of tags that have been known problems, and did so before I became a moderator.

The system and moderators only intervene when you target specific users. The system will automatically invalidate extremely rapid sequences of votes from one user to another, not from one user to bunch of posts by different users. You possibly could trip over this if there was a single user dumping a lot of garbage into the tag you're reviewing, but that's about the worst that likely would happen.

Moderators generally only act when users targeted by downvotes complain to us about the votes, and we see a clear pattern of voting coordination that goes beyond simple quality control. If you're only patrolling a tag and voting on posts independent of who posted them, you're not going to run into trouble here. Even in the cases where we decide to step in, you'd just get a warning first and could easily explain what you were doing if we made a bad call there.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not competent to write an answer of my own, but perhaps you could elaborate on what would happen if you *blindly* downvoted everything in a particular tag?  To my understanding, the system is likely to alert a moderator if you have even a moderate level of declined flags.  Close votes which expire because nobody else close voted are completely below the radar as far as I can understand.

Comment: @tripleee - Votes and flags are different things. Standard close flags aren't visible to moderators, and we aren't warned if someone gets a bunch of those declined. The flagger is, however, to let them know that their flags aren't being well-received. If you use custom flags on posts, moderators will see those, but we'd only step in if something really abusive was going on (again, generally targeting specific users). If votes or flags aren't being targeted at an individual, there's little that would appear on our radar.

Comment: What's the suggested reaction when you see "a single user dumping a lot of garbage into the tag you're reviewing?" Flag with links and mention the trend or just continue voting down/to close?

Comment: @ssube there's a suspension for contributing low quality content.

Answer (score 27):

I do the same thing, but I use a tag filter instead of watching tags. I have a filter called "bad tags" that has a bunch of tags that need to die. Some of the *questions* are OK, but just need to be retagged.

Most of these tags already have burnination requests. The rest are just some that I feel are likely to be abused.

There's a large number of posts that end up under that tab, but this means that I'm unlikely to ever vote more than once on the same user.

I prefer this method because I can use the watched tag highlighting to see questions I may actually be interested in answering. As a bonus, it doesn't increment the "followers" number.

Nothing bad has ever happened to me as a result of doing this. Just remember to take breaks and look at stuff you actually want to see once in a while.